Reversible k-morphism?
I'm reading this nLab page right now, and I'm running into an issue trying to understand $(n, r)$ categories. nLab defines them as such:

An (n, r) category is a higher category such that, essentially:
$\bullet$ all k-morphisms for $k > n$ are trivial.
$\bullet$ all k-morphisms for $k > r$ are reversible.

I would know of course what dualizing a 1-category does: I reverse every morphism in my diagram.
However, I wasn't able to find any precise critera on "reversability" after searching nLab and the wider internet, and I found no reference to this in Saunders Mac lane's book.
To add further confusion, here nLab defines the $(\infty , 0)$ category as having every $j$-morphism (for $j > 0$) as being an equivalence. What am I supposed to make of this? Are reversible morphisms considered equivalences now in the general case? What does reversability precisely mean here? Is there some reversability criteria that I'm not aware of? Is there a source or webpage I can look at that discusses this? Thanks in advance.

For your information, Saunders Mac Lane is a single person.

haha, fixed that!

"reversible" is probably being used as a vague version of "invertible" here. The reason is that it is tricky to define "invertible" (hence also "equivalence") correctly in higher dimensions.

The Idea section is informal, the Definition section is formal.
